Clarification on Parameters and Assumptions of the Parabolic Model for Overhead Power Lines
I am working on a mathematical investigation comparing the parabolic and catenary models for overhead power lines. I need to clarify some details about the parabolic model, specifically its parameters and assumptions.
Could someone provide a detailed explanation of the following aspects of the parabolic model for overhead power lines?
Parameters:
What are the critical parameters used in the parabolic model for power lines?
How are the span (L), sag (S), and load per unit length (w) defined and used in this model?
Assumptions:
What assumptions are typically made in the parabolic model (e.g., small sag approximation, uniform load distribution)?
How do these assumptions impact the model's accuracy, especially in scenarios with larger sags?
Practical Application:
Are there specific conditions or limits under which the parabolic model is generally used or avoided?
How does the parabolic model compare with the catenary model in terms of accuracy and applicability for different power lines?
I appreciate any resources, explanations, or references to help clarify these aspects.
Thank you!

Telephone companies will have done a lot of work on this and so will electric power companies. Another source could be tomes on bridges - they use catenary curves etc.

The basic difference between a parabolic cable and a catenary cable is how the rate of loading varies. The parabolic cable has loading constant along span direction whereas for a catenary the loading is constant per unit cable length arc.
Equilibrium of the curved cable segment from vertex to any point upwards is ( q is weight per unit length along x- or span direction the where Q is the weight of the lower segment shown thick, H is tension force at the vertex, F is cable tension at any point.)
The ordinary differential equation for parabolic cable is:
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}= \tan \phi =\frac{ Q}{H}=\frac{\int q ~dx}{H} \tag 1 $$
$ H/q= BL $ has dimensions of length. It is the Breaking Length of straight cable that can be hung/supported from a point acting as a concentrated force.

Integrating
$$ y = \frac{x^2}{2 BL}~ \to y1 = \frac{x1^2}{2BL}\tag 2 $$
if we choose boundary condition symmetrically at lowest vertex point. Now y1 is sag and x1 is half bridge span.
For the catenary cable
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}= \tan \phi =\frac{ Q}{H}=\frac{\int q ~ds}{H} =\frac{\int  \sec \phi ~dx}{BL} \tag 3 $$
which when integrated to symmetric conditions gives
$$ y = BL~ \cosh ( x/BL ) \tag 4 $$
Geometrically the shallow catenary $ \phi<< 1 $ can be approximated to a parabola near the vertex at lowest point.
